# Unable to get the Downlaod Url of a file from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

i m working on an Android project based on pdf generation and get stored on the firebase storage, and get the Download url to download the file, my file is automatically selected and uploaded at the time of pdf generation but i m not able to get the download url of the file uploaded on firebase storage. I m kinda new to firebase so here is the code below

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
    File file = new File(path, "report.pdf");
    Uri filepicked = Uri.fromFile(file);
    StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(cusname +" "+"report" + "." +".pdf");
    fileReference.putFile(filepicked);
    StorageReference storageReference = fileReference.child(cusname+" "+"report");
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String link = uri.toString();
            DatabaseReference reference = mDatabaseRef.child(cusname+" "+
                    "report");
            reference.setValue(link);
        }
    });
```

and as i run the application at the part of uploading it uploads the file but dont give me the download Url and shows me this error

```
//StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems here.  First, putFile is asynchronous and takes some time to finish, but your code isn't waiting on the upload to complete.  It's trying to access a download immediately after the upload starts, but before the upload is complete.

Also, you're building a different storage reference object to fetch the download URL.  The first has .pdf appended, but the other does not.  Why aren't you using the same reference that you used to upload the file?

Comment: Thank you very much it worked i provided a delay in it and used the same reference it helped it get the URL Thank you so much..